# Is it possible to create multiple queues and exchanges from config using RabbitMQ in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a config :

```
rabbitQueueProps: 
    myQueue1:
      routingKey: route1
      exchangeName: myExchange
      exchangeType: DIRECT
      maxPriority: 10
    myQueue2:
      routingKey: route2
      exchangeName: myExchange
      exchangeType: DIRECT
      maxPriority: 7
```

For the above Config, I want to create exchanges and queues dynamically.

I have tried this, but did't created any exchange or queue.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class DynamicQueueSetUp {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    @Autowired
    RabbitAdminConfiguration rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitQueueConfiguration rabbitQueueConfig;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        log.info("validating/creating new queues");
        Map<String, RabbitProps> rabbitQueueprops = rabbitQueueConfig.getRabbitQueueProps();

        rabbitQueueprops.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(queueName -> {
            RabbitProps rabbitProps = rabbitQueueConfig.getRabbitQueueProps().get(queueName);
            Optional<Properties> queueProps = Optional.ofNullable(rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName));
            if (!queueProps.isPresent()) {
                log.info("rabbitProps {} , queueName {} ", rabbitProps, queueName);
                Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
                args.put("x-max-priority", rabbitProps.getMaxPriority());
                if (DIRECT.equalsIgnoreCase(rabbitProps.getExchangeName())) {
                    DirectExchange directExchange = new DirectExchange(rabbitProps.getExchangeName(), true, false);
                    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, args);
                    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
                    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(directExchange);
                    Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with(rabbitProps.getRoutingKey());
                    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "myQueue1", "myQueue2" })
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

Is it possible create queues and exchanges dynamically from config or do I need to declare Exchange, Queue and Binding @Bean for each entry individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of declaring `Declarable` objects such as `Exchange`, `Queue` and `Binding` altogether from your configuration natively.

What you can do best is to use `Declarables`:

```java
@Bean
public Declarables declarables() {
    return new Declarables(
        new DirectExchange("exchangeName", false, true),
        new Queue("queueName", false, false, true),
        new Binding("destination", DestinationType.QUEUE, "exchange", "routingKey", null));
}
```

to declare your AMQP objects on RabbitMQ altogether in Java code. But you still need to fetch `"queueName"`, `"exchangeName"` etc. from config. So I suggest creating helper classes as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public QueueHelper {

    @Value("my.queue.names") private List<String> queueNames;

    @Bean
    public Declarables queueDeclarable() {
        Declarables declarables = new Declarables();
        declarables.addAll(queueNames.stream().map(queueName -> new Queue(queueName, false, false, true)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return declarables;
    }
}
```

So, without changing the code but just modifying the `my.queue.names` in your configuration you can dynamically define your queues through your config.

So if you have `my.queue.names=queue1,queue1` you'll get two queues; `queue1` and `queue2`, but if you have `my.queue.names=queue1,queue2,queue3` you'll get three queues named `queue1`, `queue2` and `queue3`.